# In how many ways can a row of k seats be filled from a set of n people?

Tags: combinatorics

Sorry if this seems really basic, but probability's not my strong suit.

The answer says it is n!/(n-k)! ways, but I don't understand how the writer got the denominator. The numerator makes sense, given that the total combinations possible (if there was a row of n chairs) would result in n!. But how would one know to use (n-k)! to get rid of scenarios that are counted more than once?

Comment: Do you know how to make selections of $k$ chairs out of $n$? ${n \choose k}$

Comment: Note that $\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!} = \underbrace{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)}_{k~\text{terms}}$.  We choose who sits in the first seat in $n$ ways, then we choose who from those are left sits in the second seat in $n-1$ ways, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Since there are $k$ seats ($k \leq n$), the number of ways of picking $k$ people to sit out of the $n$ people is $\binom{n}{k}$. Now the number of ways of arranging these $k$ people is $k!$, so the answer is $$\binom{n}{k} \times k! = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$